# Fix android studio Firebase Ads Library showing errors after update

Tags: android, android-studio, interstitial

After updating the following firebase ads libraries

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.1.0'
```

My android studio project keeps throwing errors such as this

```
 cannot find symbol
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

 Cannot resolve symbol 'InterstitialAd'
```

It is fine if i revert back to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.4.0'
```

But to implement some function and native ad in my app, I need the latest firebase Ads Library. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in version-20 the classes are changed. Use this;

> com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;

See more details [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration)